# Como faço para completar nome da tabela SQL com valor de uma variável?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sqlite

quero criar uma tabela nova para cada cliente e quero completar a tabela conta com o id do cliente que estou criando em outra tabela como no exemplo a baixo:

`await db.run('create table if not exists conta**ID** (saldo INTEGER);')`

para cada cliente criado na tabela de clientes ele ganha um id automaticamente, eu gostaria de pegar o id dele guardar em uma variavel para completar o nome dessa nova tabela com o valor dele, como faço isso?

Answer (score -1):

Geralmente é só colocar o retorno da query, que provavelmente retorna os dados inseridos, dentro de uma variável.

```
const user = await db.run('insert into users...')
```

Depois é só o ID pegar com `user.id`